# Limited iterations with Poisson

Tags: r, for-loop, poisson

I have the following script and my problem is that if I set `n<-10000` works ok, but if I increase the number of iterations to 100.000 or even 1.000.000 I get N/As (after a specific point) in the outcome vector.

```
max_mile <- 14
max_time <- 12


# for the first car
m1_mile <- 16
sd1_mile <- 2.5
# for the second car
m2_mile <- 8
sd2_mile <-15

# for 40% one and 60% two cars
p_first_car <- 0.4
p_second_car <- 0.6
m_mile <- p_first_car*m1_mile + p_second_car*m2_mile
sd_mile <- sqrt((p_first_car*sd1_mile)^2+(p_second_car*sd2_mile)^2)

m_time <- 20
a_time <- 1/m_time

a_time_e <- 20^2/15
b_time_e <- 20/15

a_damage <- 1
b_damage <- 0.01

# number of iterations
n <- 10000

total_cost_d <- rep(NA, n)
n_d <- rep(NA, n)
for(i in 1:n){
  n_d[i] <- rpois(1, 10)
  mileage_d <- abs(n_d[i], m_mile, sd_mile))
  time_d <- rexp(n_d[i], a_time)
  damage_d <- rgamma(n_d[i], a_damage, b_damage)
  clients_d = data.frame(n_d, mileage_d, time_d, damage_d)
  clients_d$n_d <- NULL
  clients_d_filtered <- clients_d %>% filter(time_d<max_time & mileage_d<max_mile)
  total_cost_d[i] <- round(sum(clients_d_filtered$damage_d), 0)
}

total_cost_d
```

Also, the exact same script with the only modification being `n_d[i] <- rpois(1, 100)` works perfectly with 1.000.000 iterations.
Thank you!

Comment: What's happening on the line `mileage_d <- abs(n_d[i], m_mile, sd_mile))`? There looks like there is one too many closing parenthesis. Also you are passing three parameters to `abs()` which just expects 1 (assuming you are using base absolute value function. You should be getting syntax errors when trying to run that code.

Comment: I am terribly sorry this line is as follows ```mileage_d <- abs(rnorm(n_d[i], m_mile, sd_mile))```, I try to simulate positive values of a specific Normal. Still not working

Comment: Please define all your variables so we can actually run and test the code. Even better, makes sure to include a seed with `set.seed()` so we can get the same random variables as you. It doesn't seem likely that you will get different behaviors for different values of `n`

Comment: Sure. I have edited my question. What seems really strange to me is that in the same script I have a similar loop with the only difference being the lamda of Poisson. Instead of 10 it is 100. Thank you!

Comment: Eventually I solve it. The problem was that simulating from a Poisson(10) distribution there is a chance o getting zero as result. This was not the case with small number of iterations because the sample was small but by increasing iterations the possibilities of getting zero increases. When I got a zero then the loop could not continue. I had to add a ```next()``` to avoid zeros.